# How to disable button after clicked using jsp request.getParameter()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I want to disable button after clicked but using request.getParameter(). I wrote code in `form tag`:

```
<button name="Save" value="Save" onclick="this.disable=true;"> Save</button>
```

and after that:

```
  <% 
    if(request.getParameter("Save")!=null)
    {
  %>
   <SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">​
    this.disable=true;
   </script>
  <% 

%>`
```

Of course I know that I can use onClick():`<button name="Save" value="Save" onclick="this.disable=true;"> Save</button>` but I want to do this another way with request.

Comment: The "Save" parameter will not be available, but only in the response after the "Save" button containing form had been submitted. If you return to the same view it will work, but I sense this is not what you are trying to do.

Comment: Could you write more details?

Comment: To be able to recommend the correct solution, please describe the use case that includes your view.

Comment: Generally I have list of buttons and after clicked i want to disactive them. In the same time i want to open new page and send to it id/value to identify which was cliked

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the request parameter like you did because the request only exist after you submit. You need to write it completely in JavaScript. On click disable button.